# Will hdfs preserve the column headers of CSV file?

Tags: hadoop

I have a huge csv file with column headers . My question is when i put the csv file in HDFS, will all the files in the cluster will keep the headers or it will be header less.

Comment: if you copy files to HDFS they will be copied as they are

Answer (score 1):

If you simply copy file to HDFS using command line or API then yes, the file will not change in any way (headers will be kept).

But if you are planning to use it as a hive table, then you'll want to remove headers before loading file and then create appropriate hive table.